# Trying to concatenate a string and variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to concatenate in Jquery and am having lots of trouble. Everytime the page loads I want the $ sign to  appear in my div. I was able to do it in Javascript but in Jquery I can't seem to get it.

Here is my js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#donation-amount').keyup(function() {
         var amount = $('#display-amount').text($(this).val());
    });
})
```

I've tried this

`$('.display-amount').append("<span>" + '$' + amount + "</span>");`

which gives me this

[image]

I have also tried making a span tag and gave it a class of dollar and tried these 2 things

```
 $('#dollar').val('$' + amount);
    $('#dollar').val($('$').val() + amount);
```

Here is my form

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <fieldset>
        <legend class="text-center">How much would you like to donate</legend>
        <div class="choose-pricing">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue active">10</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue">15</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue">20</button>
            <input type="Custom" name="donation-amount" class="inpt-first form-control" id="donation-amount" onclick="if(this.defaultValue == this.value) this.value = ''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" value="Custom">
            <input type="hidden" name="donation-amount-value" id="donation-amount-value">
          </div>
          <div class="money-donate">
            <div class="display-amount" id="display-amount">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `css` `:before` to display `$` character

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#donation-amount').keyup(function() {
    var amount = $('#display-amount').text($(this).val());
  });
})
```

```css
#display-amount:before {
  content: "$";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <fieldset>
      <legend class="text-center">How much would you like to donate</legend>
      <div class="choose-pricing">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue active">10</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue">15</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue">20</button>
          <input type="Custom" name="donation-amount" class="inpt-first form-control" id="donation-amount" onclick="if(this.defaultValue == this.value) this.value = ''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" value="Custom">
          <input type="hidden" name="donation-amount-value" id="donation-amount-value">
        </div>
        <div class="money-donate">
          <div class="display-amount" id="display-amount">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `amount` equal to a jQuery object, which is getting evaluated to a string `[object Object]`. Try something like this:

```
var input = $("#input");
var output = $("#output");

input.keyup(function() {

    var amount = input.val();
    output.text('$' + amount);
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4a68zme/2/)

You need to capture the value of the input and *then* insert it into the output container, on keyup. Pretty straightforward.

Also : if you can do this with vanilla javascript, why use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

#### Approach 1 :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#donation-amount').keyup(function() {
         var amount = $('#display-amount').text('$' + $(this).val());
    });
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="text-center">How much would you like to donate</legend>
            <div class="choose-pricing">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue active">10</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue">15</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue">20</button>
                    <input type="Custom" name="donation-amount" class="inpt-first form-control" id="donation-amount" onclick="if(this.defaultValue == this.value) this.value = ''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" value="Custom">
                    <input type="hidden" name="donation-amount-value" id="donation-amount-value">
                </div>
                <div class="money-donate">
                    <div class="display-amount" id="display-amount">$</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Approach 2 :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#donation-amount').keyup(function() {
         var amount = $('#display-amount').text($(this).val());
    });
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="text-center">How much would you like to donate</legend>
            <div class="choose-pricing">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue active">10</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue">15</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default selectvalue">20</button>
                    <input type="Custom" name="donation-amount" class="inpt-first form-control" id="donation-amount" onclick="if(this.defaultValue == this.value) this.value = ''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" value="Custom">
                    <input type="hidden" name="donation-amount-value" id="donation-amount-value">
                </div>
                <div class="money-donate">
                    <div class="display-amount">$<span id="display-amount"></span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```